# Recover direct summands in derived category?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, direct-sum, derived-categories

Let $E,F\in D^b(X)$, where $D^b(X)$ denotes the derived category of coherent sheaves on some smooth variety $X$. I am thinking about the following question:

> If $E \oplus E[1] \simeq F \oplus F[1]$, is it true that $E \simeq F$?

One can also ask the similar question where 'shifted by $1$' replaced by 'shifted by $n$' for any fixed $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Do you have any motivation to such a question?

Comment: @AlexeyDo Yes. For example, one can consider the embedding $f: X \to X \times \mathbb P^1$, and the proposed question is to ask if $f^*f_*$ is conservative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take any $X$ which has a vector bundle which is stably free but not free; say there is a vector bundle $A$ has rank $n$ that is not free but $A\oplus\mathcal{O}_X$ is free.  Then consider $E=\mathcal{O}_X\oplus A[1]\oplus \mathcal{O}_X[2]$ and $F=\mathcal{O}_X\oplus \mathcal{O}_X^n[1]\oplus \mathcal{O}_X[2]$.  Then $E\oplus E[1]\cong F\oplus F[1]\cong \mathcal{O}_X\oplus\mathcal{O}_X^{n+1}[1]\oplus \mathcal{O}_X^{n+1}[2]\oplus \mathcal{O}_X[3]$ but $E$ and $F$ are not isomorphic.  (A similar example would work for shifts by an arbitrary nonzero integer; just multiply all the shifts here by that integer.)

Comment: Thanks! Could you also say a little bit about the $n=0$ case? I guess we can conclude $E=F$, but I do know how to approach.

Comment: You mean if you shift by $0$?  I highly doubt that $E\oplus E\cong F\oplus F$ implies $E\oplus F$ in general, but I don't know a counterexample off the top of my head.